# How to make conditions that depends on one statement

Tags: java, if-statement, logic, conditional-statements

So I got this homework to build a contactor for a class `Date`, check whether the data is valid, and in my checks, I should consider the possibility of a leap year. so I got the variable `IsValidInJan`:

```java
 boolean IsValidInJan = month != 8 || 
 (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 &&  year % 400 == 0);
```

and then I have an if statement that checks out whether the data is invalid (note that the body of the if statement should be activated if the data is invalid, and not the other way around)

```java
if(year > current_year || (daysByMonth[month] < day && !IsValidInJan)|| day < 0 )
```

ignore the most of it. the thing is that inside the brackets (at the middel of the if stament) i want the following condtional logic:

*if `!IsValidInJan` is true, then the whole stament is `true` (only inside the brackets)*

*if `!IsValidInJan` is `false`, then check if `daysByMonth[month] < day`
is true or not and take that as the result (only inside the brackets)*

I don't want to separate it to smaller `if` statements.

How can I achieve such logic?

Comment: By using or instead of and, and changing the conditions the other way around so they’re checked in that order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if !IsValidInJan is true, then the whole stament is true (only inside
>   the brackets)
>
> if !IsValidInJan is false, then check if daysByMonth[month] < day is
>   true or not and take that as the result (only inside the brackets)

You can use the Conditional-OR operator `||` to achieve that.

Conditional operators (`||` and `&&`) exhibit "short-circuiting" behavior, which means that the second operand is evaluated only if needed. More info in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

So, you can write your expression as `!IsValidInJan || daysByMonth[month] < day`

Here, if the first operand `!IsValidInJan` is **true**, then the second operand is not evaluated.

If `!IsValidInJan` is **false**, only then `daysByMonth[month] < day` is evaluated and its result is passed as the result of the whole expression.

Therefore, your `if` statement can be written as:

```
if(year > current_year || (!IsValidInJan || daysByMonth[month] < day) || day < 0)
```